# How to convert high resolution images to low images in balzor server side

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor

In our server side blazor project we want to convert high resolution of TIFf images or any other type of Image type into low resolution image without any loss of image clearity and save it on azure blob storage.
So what is the best way or solution  to achieve this functionality in blazor.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `system.drawing.common` `NuGet` package to perform high quality resizes. This package is a cross-platform version the windows specific `system.drawing`.

There are other image processing libraries like `ImageSharp` that are good alternatives.

I have never done it myself but read this sometime back, but not able to find the article now. There are tutorials how it is done.

Hope this gives you some direction.